# How can I prevent race conditions in Cassandra?

Tags: partitioning, locking, nosql, cassandra

Lets say two users simultaneously want to access the same partition of a Cassandra table:

Suppose we have a Cassandra table called "user_data" that stores user data. The table has a partition key column "user_id" and another column "balance" that holds the user's account balance.

User A reads the current balance (= 100) from the partition with user_id "123".
At the same time, User B also reads the same balance (=100) from the partition with user_id "123".
User A intends to deduct an amount of 50 from their balance and stores the result (50) back into the partition with user_id "123" in the "user_data" table.
Simultaneously, User B also intends to deduct an amount of 30 from their balance and stores the result (=70) into the partition with user_id "123". Since User B read the previous balance (100) and not the updated value from User A (=50), the deducted amount by User B is calculated based on an outdated balance.
Both users now have different values for the balance in the partition with user_id "123" (User A has 50, and User B has 70), leading to inconsistencies and unexpected results.

What is the best way to solve this problem?
The scenario is highly unlikely to occur in my application, but could I use ZooKeeper to lock individual user partitions during read or write operations? And how could this impact the performance?

I would appreciate every answer. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

This is a problem that will be solved soon when ACID transactions is added to Cassandra 5.0 ([CEP-15](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/x/FQRACw)).

When it lands, a transaction would look something like this:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
    LET fromBalance = (SELECT balance FROM accounts
        WHERE holder='alice');
    IF fromBalance.balance >= 20 THEN
        UPDATE accounts SET balance -= 20 WHERE holder='alice';
        UPDATE accounts SET balance += 20 WHERE holder='bob';
    END IF
COMMIT TRANSACTION ;
```

From this example, the `fromBalance` will be isolated from all other requests and locked for the life of the transaction. Additionally, BOTH `UPDATE` statements within the transaction are executed atomically.

Here are some blog posts if you'd like to read more about the details:

- Patrick McFadin, ["An Apache Cassandra Breakthrough: ACID Transactions at Scale"](https://thenewstack.io/an-apache-cassandra-breakthrough-acid-transactions-at-scale/)
- Aaron Ploetz, ["ACID Transactions Change the Game for Cassandra Developers"](https://thenewstack.io/acid-transactions-change-the-game-for-cassandra-developers/)

Comment: Ha!  We basically had the same idea here, including posting my article.  LOL.

Comment: Thank you both for the quick responses. Is there already a release date? I only found one article talking about spring 2023.

Comment: Hi @Erick Ramirez I was wondering if they applied this feature on Cassandra 5.0 from the website seems only for 5.1 but couldn't find a docker

Answer (score 3):

And you now understand why the "read before write" approach is considered an anti-pattern in Cassandra.  This is because, by the time you execute the write, the data you initially read could have changed.

> What is the best way to solve this problem?

There really isn't.  This is why Cassandra is known as a highly available, eventually consistent database.  There's no locking; the last write "wins."

One possible way around this, would be to create a semaphore in a microservice which handles all operations (read and writes).  It could then keep track of active "transactions" by a certain process by partition.  Any other process would have to wait for that semaphore to clear its hold on that partition, first.

> And how could this impact the performance?

Performance would be terrible.  I mean, for this to work we're talking about deliberately putting something in place to hinder reads and writes.  Bottom line, is that Cassandra was just not built to provide the type of operational isolation that's being described here.

That being said, this *will* be possible in Apache Cassandra 5.0, which will have fully-ACID transactions.  We're shooting for its release by EOY.  I wrote an article about that here: [ACID Transactions Change the Game for Cassandra Developers](https://thenewstack.io/acid-transactions-change-the-game-for-cassandra-developers/)